# How does the Sorcerer flare card work with non-viable races in Cosmic Encounter?

Tags: cosmic-encounter

This issue came up in a game of Cosmic Encounter tonight and we were unsure how to resolve it.  The wild effect on the Sorcerer flare card allows the player to force the two main players (offense and defense) to swap powers. It then says this swap continues after the encounter is over.  We took this to mean that the swap is permanent, which is pretty freaking powerful!

However, adding to the confusion was that the defending player only had two of his home planets colonized at the time, meaning that his power was removed at that time because his race was "non-viable."  The attacker had three of his home planets, so his power was active.  We could not agree on whether this meant the defending player would get to use the offensive player's power, while the offensive player would have no power (because the defending player "traded" his non-power), or whether the powers would swap but then the defending player would lose it immediately because they still only had two home planets colonized.

In addition, is the trade really permanent?  That seems like a very powerful ability to be Wild, especially when the Super ability for the Sorcerer on the same card is relatively weak (allows them to use their ability to swap Encounter cards even as an ally)

Answer (score 6):

The change is permanent. (Yes, it is powerful, but Wild flares are often powerful; frequently more powerful than the Super, which is usually just an enhancement to the base power.)

The fact that the change is permanent also helps to clarify your question. The defender isn't using the attacker's power; the defender is using their own power, which happens to be the power the attacker started the challenge with. Since it's their own power, its usage is controlled by the number of their home bases.